# Multiplying Named Arrays with Fixed Arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do something fairly simple, which is complicated to explain.

My objective is to convert and sum numbers that are originally in different currencies into GBP.

Simply put:

If I have

```
10 HKD
10 SGS
```

I want to be able to create a sumproduct where 10 HKD is multiplied by 10 GBPHKD and 10 SGS is multiplied by 10 GBPSGD.

In the future, if a new currency appears, I want the value to be multiplied by GBP[currency] before it is summed up with the rest.

I've tried all sorts of options, incl using

sumproduct(Indirect(concatenate(A1:A2),"GBP"),B1:B2)

But nothing gives :-(

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: To be clear, I have created named ranges for every currency e.g. HKDGBP that show the FX for that pair.

Comment: Need more details with sample data. Put a screenshot of your data sample.

Comment: Perhaps you need `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,N(INDIRECT("GBP"&B1:B2)))`, although it would make far more sense to have a simple lookup table for your rates rather than refer to them indirectly like this.

Comment: Completely resolved it! Wow thank you - never seen the function N(). Makes me realise HOW MUCH I still have to learn... you cannot imagine the hours I spent on this before posting. Thank you so much.